# Why is the default search searching only the current page, not the whole site?

Tags: search, view, drupal-7

The default search doesn't find items which is for example on the second page in a view.
Why?

I use Drupal 7.

Comment: in views search add a filter criterie "Indexed Node: Content type" and select the contents type

Comment: @  Akremi Mourad
There is no Indexed Node in the criterias of views. Should I install a module for this? Which?

Comment: There is the module  "Search views" and  "Search API"  to create your views